# Proof Linear maps (linear algebra done right)

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I had proven this problem by using matrices but when I went to look at the solution I found another solution that I didn't understand even after looking at it for quite some time:
[image] The marked area is where I got lost. How come without even defining $T$ first he says it has to be equal to $A_{1,1}  , A_{2,1} ,\ldots$?
How does he know it has to be equal to that?
Try to explain it in simple terms (I am a sophomore(15)).
Here is the rest of the solution:
[image]

Comment: This is the fourth question you are posting whose main content are pictures of text/formulas. Let me urge you again to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset your questions. We also don't need multiple pages of your textbook when your question just concerns a few lines of a proof, that could easily be typed in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is that any linear map $T \in \mathcal L(\mathbf F^n, \mathbf F^m)$ can be written as
$$
  T(x_1, \dots, x_n) = (A_{1,1} x_1 + \cdots + A_{1,n} x_n, \dots, A_{m,1} x_1 + \cdots + A_{m,n} x_n)
$$
for specific numbers $A_{i,j} \in \mathbf F$ (that depend on $T$, of course). We need to find candidates for these numbers to be able to attempt to prove the claim, but how do we find these candidates?

Well, the trick is to *assume* for a moment that the claim is correct. We can then try and evaluate $T$, and we will do so for the vectors $e_k \in \mathbf F^n$. Writing $e_k$ in the form $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$, we get $x_k = 1$ and $x_j = 0$ for $j \neq k$. We can plug this into the formula for $T$ above and get
$$
  T(e_k) = (A_{1,k}, \dots, A_{m,k}) \quad \text{for $k=1,\dots,n$}
$$
(which is a compact form of writing the thing you circled blue). So, assuming that a given $T$ can be written in this way, there is only one possibility for $A_{i,j}$: Namely, $(A_{1,k}, \dots, A_{m,k})$ needs to be equal to $T(e_k)$ and the value $T(e_k)$ is determined by $T$. So far, we have only used that $T$ is a map, but not that it is a *linear* map.

In other words, these values for $A_{i,j}$ are the only ones that can possibly work, because if we evaluate at $e_k$ the two sides of the equation will not agree otherwise. The rest of the proof then checks that they actually *do* work (i.e. show that the equation also holds for all other vectors), by invoking what we have not used yet: the linearity of $T$. (If $T$ is not linear, we can still find values $A_{i,j}$ in the same way, but it will turn out that the map $T$ will not follow the formula in the claim.)

Comment: Sorry for my late response but I want to thank you for your explanation it was very easy to understand and it made it very clear.

Comment: If the answer helped you, you can accept it by clicking the checkmating next to it. This will remove it from the list of unanswered questions (and give me some points).